# how use two different logos

Tags: magento-1.9, theme

I have magento 1.9.1 with the theme "trego". On the home page I have black background, there I want to use a logo with white color, the product pages have white background, there I require a logo with black color.

how can I use different logos for different pages?

Example logo code:

```
 <a href="http://example.com/" title="Magento Commerce" class="logo"><img src="http://example.com/skin/frontend/default/trego/images/logo.png" alt="Magento Commerce"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You will deal with templates and the `local.xml` file, which you can create under your theme folder.

I will assume some configurations:

- That your theme is under `app/skin/frontend/rwd/yourtheme/`;
- That you have a `local.xml` file inside `app/skin/frontend/rwd/yourtheme/layout`;
- That exists a `header.phtml` file in `app/skin/frontend/rwd/default/template/page/html/`;
- That you have 2 different `.phtml` files, each one with the HTML for the corresponding logo: `whitelogo.phtml` and `blacklogo.phtml`;

So, first you copy the `header.phtml` from the above dir into `app/skin/frontend/rwd/yourtheme/template/page/html/` and edit it: put `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml("logo"); ?>` in header where you want the logo to appear.

Copy the `whitelogo.phtml` and `blacklogo.phtml` also in this same directory.

Then you edit the `local.xml` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <catalog_product_index>
        <reference name="header">
            <block type="core/template" name="logo" template="page/html/blacklogo.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_index>
    <cms_index_index>
        <reference name="header">
            <block type="core/template" name="logo" template="page/html/whitelogo.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </cms_index_index>
</layout>
```

And this should work. In your homepage you will have the white logo and in the product page the other logo.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this fairly easy with php or css.  If you decide to go the php route you are probably going to want to setup another system config option for a second logo option.

The easiest, but not so managable, way to accomplish this would be within CSS.  You could easily set the logo to a background-image and change this based on the body url (i.e. cms-index-index).